# How to track postgres archive log files

Tags: postgresql, backup

In SQL Server, there is a msdb..backupset table which keep tracks of which backup it take.  How to capture which archivelog is archived and what is the starting point of this backup?

Comment: when you run `pg_start_backup` it returns you the position

Answer (score 1):

[Every online physical backup contains a text file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) `backup_label` that contains the log sequence number of the checkpoint at the start of the backup.

There is also a file with a name ending in `.backup` created in the WAL archive that contains this information.

Since 9.4 the view `pg_stat_archiver` contains information about archived WAL segments.